# Change NULL Date Value in sql

Tags: sql, null

i have problem with SQL null value in query i have null date which shows like 1900-01-01, so i tried change it to empty string. Couly somebody give an advice? My SQL - query:

```
SELECT EquipmentOC.Код,
EquipmentPlace.Участок as Участок,
[EquipmentСategory].Категория as Категория,
EquipmentOC.Имя, EquipmentOC.[Инв Номер],  FORMAT (EquipmentOC.[Дата Ввода в экспл], 'dd.MM.yy') as [Дата Ввода в экспл],
EquipmentOC.Примечание,
EquipmentOC.ППР, FORMAT (EquipmentOC.ТО, 'dd.MM.yy') as ТО,
FORMAT ( EquipmentOC.МР, 'dd.MM.yy') as МР,
EquipmentClassification.Классификатор as Классификатор, 
EquipmentLocation.Локация as Локация,
CASE WHEN EquipmentOC.ТО = '01.01.1900'  then CONVERT(DATETIME, '') END
FROM ((([EquipmentOC]
INNER JOIN [EquipmentPlace] ON [EquipmentOC].Участок = [EquipmentPlace].Код)
INNER JOIN [EquipmentСategory] ON [EquipmentOC].Категория = EquipmentСategory.Код)
INNER JOIN [EquipmentClassification] ON [EquipmentOC].Классификатор = [EquipmentClassification].Код)
INNER JOIN [EquipmentLocation] ON [EquipmentOC].Локация = [EquipmentLocation].Код
ORDER BY Convert(date,EquipmentOC.ТО,104) DESC
```

Comment: Use NULL for null values, and store your dates in date data type columns.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replies , i already found solution

```
CASE WHEN FORMAT (EquipmentOC.ТО, 'dd.MM.yy') = '01.01.00' THEN NULL else FORMAT (EquipmentOC.ТО, 'dd.MM.yy') END as ТО
```